# Go sync.WaitGroup doesnt work correctly with chromedp

Tags: go, goroutine, chromedp, waitgroup

I'm a beginner in Go, and I'm experiencing an issue related to wait groups in the code I provided below. The sync.WaitGroup seems to be causing a deadlock as it enters the Wait function before the go routine function completes. The Go routines print to the screen once, then the subsequent routines do not execute, they simply wait. How can I resolve this issue?
Thanks for your answering
`

```
func main() {
    start := time.Now()

    opts := append(chromedp.DefaultExecAllocatorOptions[:],
        chromedp.Flag("headless", true),
        chromedp.Flag("ignore-certificate-errors", true),
        chromedp.Flag("disable-dev-shm-usage", true),
        chromedp.Flag("disable-gpu", true),
        chromedp.UserAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3713.125 Safari/537.36"),
    )

    alloctx, cancel := chromedp.NewExecAllocator(context.Background(), opts...)
    defer cancel()
    ctx, cancel := chromedp.NewContext(alloctx)
    defer cancel()

    var wg sync.WaitGroup

    for i := 1; i <= 10; i++ {
        i := i
        wg.Add(1)
        go func() {
            defer wg.Done()
            err := chromedp.Run(ctx, visitAndFetch("https://example.com/?q=ka&page="+strconv.Itoa(i)))

            if err != nil {
                fmt.Println("error occurred", err)
            }

        }()

    }
    wg.Wait()
    fmt.Println(time.Since(start))

}

var title string

func visitAndFetch(url string) chromedp.Tasks {

    return chromedp.Tasks{
        chromedp.Navigate(url),
        chromedp.Nodes("article.search-result-item span#htmlContent", &titles, chromedp.ByQueryAll),
        chromedp.Nodes("article.search-result-item a.pdfLink", &links, chromedp.ByQueryAll),
        chromedp.Nodes("article.search-result-item h4.dates", &dates, chromedp.ByQueryAll),

        chromedp.ActionFunc(func(ctx context.Context) error {
            for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
                title := links[i].AttributeValue("href")
                date := dates[i].Children[0].NodeValue
                strarr := strings.Split(date, " ")

                patent := &Patent{
                    PdfLink:     title,
                    PublishDate: strarr[1],
                }
                patents = append(patents, patent)

            }
            fmt.Printf("Added %s", patents)

            return nil
        }),
    }
}
```

I'm tried different solution and debug code but i dont handle this issue

Comment: The whole point of WaitGroup is to be Wait-ed by a goroutine until all the other goroutines have called Done. I mean, you Add some number N to a wait group, spawn N goroutines and then wait for them to complete. So yes, Wait is being executed (and blocks) before the other goroutines finish. So, what's the exact problem?

Comment: @kostix Yeah i know but other go routines doesnt work after that it cause deadlock

Comment: Are you actually getting an error about a deadlock, or are you assuming that's what is happening?

Comment: Another guess in the dark: may it be that `chromedp.Run` is asynchronous? That is, it starts some task and returns almost immediately so basically it appears Wait does not wait anything useful?

Comment: @Gavin Actually I didn't receive an error message related to a deadlock it's my prediction but i have waited roughly 10 min then i terminated program

Comment: OK, so what if you remove calls to chromedp from your goroutines and leave there only deferred calls to wg.Done — do the whole thing complete in almost no time?

Comment: @kostix if i remove calls chromedp  the routines work correctly however, this time I cannot use chromedp within the scope of routines. How can I solve this?

Comment: «however, this time I cannot use chromedp within the scope of routines»–I think you could start [here](https://github.com/chromedp/chromedp/issues/541#issuecomment-565823295).